# How to obtain the user of any user in tableau API_ ID

Tags: tableau-api

I want to get anyone's user_id in tableau API, but no similar interface
how to obtain the user_id of any user in tableau API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand well your question, could you elaborate ?

If you would like the ID of each Users :

- Use the Tableau Rest API, and more specifically "[Query User On Site](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#query_user_on_site)"
- On Tableau Server you can also do it by accessing directly the Repository (PostgreSQL) : [Collect Data with the Tableau Server Repository](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_server_repo.htm)

Also there is some KB articles :

- [Exporting User List from Tableau Server](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/exporting-user-list)
- [Export a list of users from Tableau Online](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/export-a-list-of-users-from-tableau-online)